# Issue Connecting to Host Port 25

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I've been with Arvixe for many years, and recently they changed ownership and performed various migrations.  Many of their Customers have had issues.

This is ASP.NET 4.5 Web Application

Ever since their migration I'm getting an Exception when users of my Website attempt to send email through the form:
http://goo.gl/zz7FeH

Message "Unable to connect to the remote server"

InnerException {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 104.27.186.185:25"} System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}

I have checked this port with Telnet and appears to be able to connect:
telnet smtp.davincispainting.com 25

Here is the MailService Code:

```
public class EstimateContactInfo
{
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Company { get; set; }
public string Address1 { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
//public string Zip { get; set; }
public string Customer { get; set; }
public string ServiceType { get; set; }
public string JobDescription { get; set; }

public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format(@"Name: {0}<br/><br/>Company: {1}<br/><br/>Email Address: {2}<br/><br/>Phone: {3}<br/><br/>
            Address1: {4}<br/><br/>Address2: {5}<br/><br/>City: {6}<br/><br/>Sate: {7}<br/><br/>Customer: {8}<br/><br/>ServiceType: {9}<br/><br/>JobDescription: {10}",
            Name, Company, Email, Phone, Address1, Address2, City, State, Customer, ServiceType, JobDescription);
}
}

public class MailService
{

public MailService()
{

}

private bool IsValidateEmail(string email)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(email, @".*@.{2,}\..{2,}");
}

public string GetToken(int contactNum)
{
    string extendKey = string.Format("smcf-{0}{1}{2}", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmail" + contactNum.ToString()], DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
    Byte[] originalBytes;
    Byte[] encodedBytes;
    MD5 md5;

    //Instantiate MD5CryptoServiceProvider, get bytes for original password and compute hash (encoded password)
    md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(extendKey);
    encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

    //Convert encoded bytes back to a 'readable' string
    return BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
}

public void SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string content, string cc)
{
    if (!IsValidateEmail(from))
    {
        from = to;
        subject += " - invalid email";
        content += "\n\nBad email:" + content;
        cc = null;
    }
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, content);

    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    if (cc != null)
        message.CC.Add(cc);

    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.davincispainting.com", 25);

    string pwd = "ninja71";

    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, pwd);
    emailClient.Credentials = credentials;

    emailClient.Send(message);
}

public void SubmitContact(EstimateContactInfo contactInfo, int cc)
{
    //SendMail(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmail1"], System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmail1"], "Request Estimate", contactInfo.ToString(), cc > 0 ? contactInfo.Email : null);
    SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmail1"], System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmail1"], "Request Estimate", contactInfo.ToString(), cc > 0 ? contactInfo.Email : null);
}
}
```

Here is the call to MailService.cs:

```
public partial class painting_estimate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnSendGenMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailService mailService = new MailService();
            EstimateContactInfo contactInfo = new EstimateContactInfo();
            contactInfo.Name = txtGenName.Text;
            contactInfo.Company = txtGenCompany.Text;
            contactInfo.Email = txtGenEmail.Text;
            contactInfo.Phone = txtGenPhone.Text;
            contactInfo.Address1 = txtGenAddy1.Text;
            contactInfo.Address2 = txtGenAddy2.Text;
            contactInfo.City = txtGenCity.Text;
            contactInfo.State = ddGenState.Text;
            contactInfo.Customer = ddGenCustomer.SelectedItem.Text;
            contactInfo.ServiceType = ddGenJobType.SelectedItem.Text;
            contactInfo.JobDescription = txtGenMessage.Text;

            mailService.SubmitContact(contactInfo, 0);
            SubmitSuccess.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception se)
        {
            SubmitError.Visible = true;
        }

        ContactPanel.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: See webpage below for list of different port numbers.   You are testing with port 25 which is used between to mail servers.  You application is using port 587 which is a secure port used for a client mail server to submit to a mail server.  Check with your mail server to get exact parameter to use with a Microsoft SMTP Client.  The Network Credentials is probably wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: @jdweng Port 587 was actually a test that I was trying.  The actual production site uses Port 25.  I've tested with Ports 587 and Port 25.

Comment: Can you send mail using test code?  Are the ports blocked?

Comment: @jdweng I have tried sending mail using Port 25 and 587 through the website, which failed.  I'm not sure how to test with other method.

Comment: There are 4 or five different SMPT port numbers. See webpage I posted. Look at mail server help pages (or call support) to get proper settings. – jdweng 3 mins ago   edit

Comment: @jdweng Here are the ports I have tried via Telnet:  25; 587; 2525  I think the issue is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... able to connect: telnet smtp.davincispainting.com 25

But in your code:

> ```
> SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.davincispainting.com", 25);
> ```

You use here different hosts which resolve to different IP addresses: smtp.xxx resolves to 143.95.251.2 while mail.xxx resolves to 104.27.186.185. And connecting to port 25 on the first works while on the second not.

Comment: I was under the impression that smtp.xxx and mail.xxx pointed to the same SMTP ?  How would I resolve this?

Comment: Paul : I keep on saying contact the mail server website.  Each mail server has different parameters.  Sometimes the mail server parameters change so you must contact the mail server.

Comment: Also you are using Network credentials which may not be correct.  Is the local PC password server the same as the mail server?  You may need to use default credentials where the user login to the PC is the same account/password as mail server.  You also may need to use a proxy server to get through the firewall if the SMPT is blocked by a firewall.  Check your virus protection and firewall to make sure the ports aren't being blocked.

Comment: @jdweng perhaps the server parameters have changed, because the new Host Company changed something, although it's the same Server Name. The credentials haven't been changed.  I'm not sure if it's a firewall problem as this issue is happening on the website on the server.

Comment: Are you using an intranet Outlook Mail Server or a Internet POP Mail Server?  I assume you can get the emails manually using the same Credentials.  I've seen cases where a POP server change SMTP port numbers going from a non secure port number to a secure port number.  You will not be able to get to a POP mail server if youir intranet firewall has the port number blocked without going to a proxy server.  You will need to talk to your MIS people to find out how to get through the firewall using a proxy server.

Comment: @jdweng I'm wondering if this could be a Cloudflare issue.  I'm not using any Intranet, this is just a simple website form to send email via port 25.

Comment: Again, you must check with the mailserver to determine the correct protocol.  You are dealing with a POP mail server and must use the same port number as the server is listening with.  Most mailserver are "NOT" using port 25 which isn't secure.  Then you must check your virus checker and firewall to make sure the port isn't blocked.